# Jersey: Inject Spring component into ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey 1.4 ea together with Spring 3.0 and the `jersey-spring` integration. Integrating Jersey and Spring works fine for resource classes as described [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring). 
How ever I want to inject a spring component into a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4-SNAPSHOT/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) to do some pre-processing of requests.

```
@Component
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    // UserManager is a declared spring component
    // Injecting it should work somehow
    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        System.out.println(userManager);
        // prints out null on request
    }
}
```

Both the filter and the user manager bean are registered when I deploy the application to Glassfish. I wonder what am I doing wrong. Is there a way to inject a spring managed bean into a ContainerRequestFilter?

**UPDATE**

Kind of solved. The issue is that Jersey does not obtain Spring beans if these beans are Java proxies (opposed to generated proxy classes). The problem can be solved by instructing Spring to ALWAYS use proxy classes instead of Java Proxies by specifying the `proxy-target-class="true"` attribute in the respective parts of a spring configuration. In my scenario I had to specify it on a `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />`.

See [here](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/AW-Jersey-ContainerRequestFilter-as-Spring-component-td5724265.html) for a more detailed analysis and a possible fix on that.

Comment: In your solution, how that SecurityFilter was registered in the web.xml file or somewhere else? I have an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/45509183/4636715 in which the ContainerRequestFilter is not visited at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing with Jersey 1.6 and Spring 3.0.5.  Using the debugger, I can tell that even though my code is marked with @Component, both Spring and Jersey will instantiate their own copy of of this class:

```
@Path("/beams")
@Produces("text/xml")
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class BeamsResource {
}
```

There's some chatter that this will be added in a future version of Jersey, but it doesn't seem to be working now.  I know this is a hideous solution, but I'm using a static member variable to hook together Jersey and Spring for the time being.  Bleh.

Comment: I finally came across a solution for this. Debugging the code it turned out that it is an issue in the way how Jersey obtains Spring beans from the context. My thoughts are documented http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/AW-Jersey-ContainerRequestFilter-as-Spring-component-td5724265.html